# Using SF Pro font on MiKTeX (Mac)

Tags: xetex, miktex, mac

I recently downloaded the SF Pro font from https://developer.apple.com/fonts/ on a MacBook Pro with MiKTeX installed. However, when I try to use it with XeLaTeX, the log says the font probably doesn't exist, even though I can use it on Word, Keynote, etc. In general, it seems that any downloaded fonts won't work. Any suggestions?

(Edit:)
In the following example, changing `SF Pro` with `DIN Alternate` or `Futura` (which are system fonts in macOS) will work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont{SF Pro}

\begin{document}
Hello LaTeX.
\end{document}
```

In log:

`Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "SF Pro/B" (it probably doesn't (fontspec)             exist).`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue?

Comment: Sure, I edited my questions already.

Comment: is this a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682881/macos-font-loading-with-xetex-and-fontspec-fails

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

After playing a lot with the fonts, I uninstalled them from the FontBook and reinstalled them dragging them into the `/Library/Fonts` folder directly. Somehow it worked, as I think it installed them system-wide.

Comment: if `/Library/Fonts` and not `~/Library/Fonts` then yes it is system wide.  I am not sure you can say fonts are "installed in the FontBook" or "uninstalled from the FontBook" but your probably refer to some maneuvers done there.